# Search in json column in framework laravel

Tags: json, laravel, database

I have a column which contains

```json
[
    {
        "type": "content",
        "data": {
            "content": "<p>\u043a\u0432\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0431\u0438\u043b\u0434\u0435\u0440<\/p>"
        }
    }
]
```

How can I get this record?

My code is:

```php
$q = $request->get('q');

$posts = Post::query()
    ->where('active', '=', true)
    ->where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
    ->latest('published_at')
    ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
        $query->whereJsonContains("content", [['type' => 'content', 'data' => ['content' => "%$q%"]]]);
    })
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: don't use the  `%`, insn't a LIKE.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

1 Add your json field to [cast](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

```
protected $casts = [
    'content' => 'array',
];
```

2 I work with russian language, when i encode to json from array i use flag:

```
`$data['content'] = json_encode($data['block'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`
```

3 My query in db looks like

```
`$posts = Post::query()->where("content", 'like',  "%$someValue%")->paginate(10);`
```